# readFile returns all lines merged together

Tags: node.js

```
.get('/listscripts/:filename', function(req, res){
    fs.readFile(__dirname + '/../public/scripts/' + req.params.filename, 'utf8', function(err, content) {
        if (err) return;
        res.send(content);
    });
})
```

I'm trying to return the content of a text file with readFile but for some reason it merges all the lines together.

So if I'm reading a file that looks like this:

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
```

Then the output of readFile will return:

```
Line 1 Line 2 Line 3
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Where do you use that file content? To display in html page? In that case the newline character is interpreted as a space. You must replace all newline character to `<br/>`.

Comment: Yeh, I'm trying to display it on an html page. Will I have to edit the file itself or is there a way to do it without editing the files?

Comment: I've answered your question, you can do it in code. But if the file content is static, the best way is to create a html page and send it to client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use that file content to display in html page, in that case the newline character is interpreted as a space. You must replace all newline character to `<br/>`:

```
app.get('/listscripts/:filename', function(req, res){
    fs.readFile(__dirname + '/../public/scripts/' + req.params.filename, 'utf8', function(err, lines) {
        if (err) {
          res.send('Error');
          return;
        };
        var content = lines.split('\n').map(function(line) {
          return line + '<br/>';
        });
        content = '<div>' + content + '</div>';
        res.set('Content-Type', 'text/html');
        res.send(content);
    });
});
```

Comment: TypeError: lines.map is not a function

I think i'm missing something...maybe an include or something?

Comment: Now the html displays ["line 1\r<br/>","line 2\r<br/>","line 3<br/>"]. 
I'm trying to display it inside a div like this (if it helps): 
<div class="col-lg-8" ng-controller="scriptContent">{{content()}}</div>

Comment: Try to add `res.set('Content-Type', 'text/html')` before `res.send` or wrap content with `div`.

Comment: Tried the new version is still not working. Result: <div>line 1<br/>,line 2<br/>,line 3<br/></div> :(

Comment: Hm, but how do you use that responce? Are you displaing that content with angular?

Comment: Yeh, I'm using Angular to display the text.

Comment: You need to use `ng-bind-html` directive and `$sce` service.

Comment: Found the problem! :) I had to envelope the content with <pre></pre>

Answer (score 0):

You can read line by line and manipulate and insert in final response as:

```
app.get('/listscripts/:filename', function(req, res){
   var result = [];   
   var readline = require('linebyline'),
       rl = readline((__dirname + '/../public/scripts/' + req.params.filename);
       rl.on('line', function (line, lineCount, byteCount) {
           console.log(lineCount, line, byteCount); // do something with the line of text
           result.push(line);            
    })
   .on('error', function (e) {
            console.log("error", e);
            // something went wrong
        })
   .on('end', function () {
       // All lines are read, file is closed now.
       res.send(result);    
   });

});
```